# ncdu does not render properly

Tags: terminal, opensuse, konsole

I noticed that `ncdu` is not rendering properly, as can be seen from the below screenshot. See that the "unknown character" symbol appears where it should be a line character:

[image]

But it doesn't happen if I use, say, my phone to ssh to my PC and run `ncdu` from there:

[image]

What can the problem be? It looks like a missing font, but what one?

I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed with Plasma desktop and Konsole, but it also happens with other terminal emulators.

Comment: The symbol that's replaced by � does show up properly elsewhere. Plus, there are other corruptions as well, the closing box corners are misplaced (note that in your other screenshot too). So definitely not a font problem, but an emulation one. Perhaps there's a shortcut escape sequence to display N line drawing characters in a single step which is emitted by your app, and this one is not understood by your terminal emulators. For start, I'd check and play with the `TERM` environment variable.

Comment: @egmont yep, seems the `TERM` environment variable is the issue. When it's set to `linux`, `ncdu` works properly, but when it is set it to `xterm-256color`, `ncdu` has problems.

Comment: It's a more complicated story then, because `konsole` sets it to `xterm-256color` by default, and that's the value that should work (assuming you're not running inside `screen` or `tmux`). It works on my system, though (Ubuntu Zesty). Not sure if it's a difference in `ncdu`, in `ncurses`, in `terminfo`, in `konsole` or what else. For the record, which other terminal emulators have you tested? How does it look like in `gnome-terminal`? What about `xterm`?

Comment: @egmont I tested with `xterm` and `mate-terminal` and both have the problem. I'm not running under screen.

Comment: What version of these?

Comment: @egmont `xterm` 327 and `mate-terminal` 1.18.1.

Comment: Thanks, they're both pretty new. I suspect there's something diffeernt in your terminfo database.